# Formatting Text into separate files

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a slight problem and do not know where to start.
I have a text file that contains the following information.

```
MINI COOPER 2007, 30,000 miles, British Racing Green, full service history, metallic paint, alloys. Great condition. £5,995 ono Telephone xxxxx xxxxx
```

I need to populate the above information in the following format

```
    <advert>
    <manufacturer></manufacturer>
    <make></make>
    <model></make>
    <price></price>
    <miles></miles>
    <image></image>
    <desc><![CDATA[desc>
    <expiry></expiry> // Any point in the future
    <url></url> // Optional
</advert>
<advert>
```

The output should be.

```
    </advert>
<advert>
    <manufacturer>MINI</manufacturer>
    <make></make>
    <model></make>
    <price>5,995</price>
    <miles>30000</miles>
    <image></image>
    <desc><![CDATA[2007, British Racing Green, full service history, metallic paint, alloys. Great condition.Telephone xxxxxx xxxxxx]]></desc>
    <expiry>Todays date 13/05/2013</expiry>
    <url></url>
</advert>
```

Any help will be create appreciated.

Comment: A `python` script, or a `gawk` script using `-F,` could help. What did you try? You won't get help without showing code that you did try...

Comment: I was after someone to point me in the right direction ..

Comment: I did point some direction.... But you have to learn enough to follow them.

Comment: I assume `<model></make>` should be `<model></model>`.

Comment: Sorry <model></model> and not <model></make>

Answer (score 1):

Since sometimes commas are part of a field and sometimes they aren't you can't use commas or anything else as a field separator so you need something like this in GNU awk (for gensub() and strftime()):

```
gawk '{
    print "<advert>"
    printf "\t<manufacturer>%s</manufacturer>\n", $1
    printf "\t<make></make>\n"
    printf "\t<model></model>\n"
    printf "\t<price>%s</price>\n", gensub(/.*£([[:digit:],]+).*/,"\\1","")
    printf "\t<miles>%s</miles>\n", gensub(/.*[[:space:]]([[:digit:],]+)[[:space:]]+miles.*/,"\\1","")
    printf "\t<image></image>\n"
    printf "\t<desc><![CDATA[%s]]></desc>\n", gensub(/.*[[:space:]]+miles[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*(.*)/,"\\1","")
    printf "\t<expiry>Todays date %s</expiry>\n", strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    printf "\t<url></url>\n"
    print "</advert>"
}' file
```

My editor seems to choke on British pound signs so here's the above script running using a # symbol instead:

```
$ cat file
MINI COOPER 2007, 30,000 miles, British Racing Green, full service history, metallic paint, alloys. Great condition. #5,995 ono Telephone xxxxx xxxxx

$ gawk '{
    print "<advert>"
    printf "\t<manufacturer>%s</manufacturer>\n", $1
    printf "\t<make></make>\n"
    printf "\t<model></model>\n"
    printf "\t<price>%s</price>\n", gensub(/.*#([[:digit:],]+).*/,"\\1","")
    printf "\t<miles>%s</miles>\n", gensub(/.*[[:space:]]([[:digit:],]+)[[:space:]]+miles.*/,"\\1","
")
    printf "\t<image></image>\n"
    printf "\t<desc><![CDATA[%s]]></desc>\n", gensub(/.*[[:space:]]+miles[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*(.
*)/,"\\1","")
    printf "\t<expiry>Todays date %s</expiry>\n", strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    printf "\t<url></url>\n"
    print "</advert>"
}' file
<advert>
        <manufacturer>MINI</manufacturer>
        <make></make>
        <model></model>
        <price>5,995</price>
        <miles>30,000</miles>
        <image></image>
        <desc><![CDATA[British Racing Green, full service history, metallic paint, alloys. Great con
dition. #5,995 ono Telephone xxxxx xxxxx]]></desc>
        <expiry>Todays date 13/05/2013</expiry>
        <url></url>
</advert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code that should get you going at least. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {

        if ($i == "miles,") {
            miles = $(i - 1)

            $i = $(i - 1) = ""
        }

        if ($i ~ /£/) {
            price = substr($i, 2)

            $i = $(i + 1) = ""
        }
    }

    gsub(/ +/, " ");

    print "<advert>"
    print "\t<manufacturer>" $1 "</manufacturer>"
    print "\t<make></make>"
    print "\t<model></make>"
    print "\t<price>" price "</price>"
    print "\t<miles>" miles "</miles>"
    print "\t<image></image>"
    print "\t<desc><![CDATA[" $0 "]></desc>"
    print "\t<expiry>" strftime( "%d/%m/%Y" ) "</expiry>"
    print "\t<url></url>"
    print "</advert>"
}
```

Results:

```
<advert>
    <manufacturer>MINI</manufacturer>
    <make></make>
    <model></make>
    <price>5,995</price>
    <miles>30,000</miles>
    <image></image>
    <desc><![CDATA[MINI COOPER 2007, British Racing Green, full service history, metallic paint, alloys. Great condition. Telephone xxxxx xxxx]></desc>
    <expiry>13/05/2013</expiry>
    <url></url>
</advert>
```

Comment: Many thanks to everyone. At least I have some where to start.

Comment: Steve. Many thanks for your post.